# c# socket virtual network

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I am c# developer, I need to create virtual private server and client in c# , I have developed a chat client/server over internet , so two clients send and receive messages with each-other , but I need these two PC to be in the same virtual network , because from first PC I need to access sample resources via http IP .

My image description is here : http://zenepe.potomi.com/dokumentat/455ss.png

In the picture described what I need . In the PC 1 and in the PC 2 is running client form of my chat application , in the server with public ip is running server form of my chat application .

I need to transform my application , I need to use web browser from PC 1 to access the website hosted in PC 2 server through my application server with public ip .

Comment: If i understand you correctly, have you seen https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx ?

Comment: The term you're looking for is not "virtual private server" but "http proxy".